# Substitute for the CredentialCache?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7

I need Windows Phone application to upload files to a web server using the `HttpWebRequest` class instance.

A server requires authentication credentials for the request.

All .net examples of uploading with a credentials rely on `CredentialCache` class object, that is used to store the credentials for the time of a program execution.

In Windows Phone, it seems like the `CredentialCache` class isn't available. What is the substitute in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use directly [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)? It is supported in in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need credentials for the life of the application, use an instance of [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that's accessible from anywhere in your application (the simplest, albeit most difficult to unit test, would be a static property or a property on your Application class).

If you need it across application instances, you can use [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to encrypt the details (stored as a byte array) so that you can persist them to isolated storage.